# typedef default template type to same name

Tags: c++, templates, typedef

**Original question:** *I have a type `template <typename CostType> struct Key` which I use in another class `UQueue`, which is also templated on `CostType`. I'd like to not have to specify `Key<CostType>` within this class. I tried `typedef Key<CostType> Key`, which did not work. Is there another workaround?*

**Edit:** The minimal example that would have exhibited the problem (if there had been one), would have been this:

```
template <typename T>
class C1 {
    T t;
};
template <typename T>
class C2 {
    typedef C1<T> C1;
    C1 c1;
};
```

However, this works (*using MSVC 2010*). I have some other error in my code which confused me into believing the typedef was illegal. Sorry about the bandwidth.

Comment: Post some code...... the definition of both classes, and the typedef.

Comment: Did you try to typedef it inside the class or outside?

Comment: How exactly does it "not work"? Do you have a compiler error? If so, what does it say?

Comment: While the question is probably not the best (neither language nor format), I think that it can be understood: The user does not want to have to specify the template argument inside a different template. He tried to add a `typedef` and that failed (**@carlpett:** here you should add **how**, *what does it mean that it did not work*?) I believe that @Luc Touraille and @Peter Alexander understood the question...

Comment: Closed in less than half an hour, that's a bit harsh, no? This leaves no time to the OP to modify its question to improve it. I'm wondering if a minimum delay before voting to close a question would not be beneficial (especially for newcomers).

Comment: @Luc - A bad question should be closed as fast as possible. :-) This one might get reopened. It is still possible to edit the closed question to get more reopen votes!

Comment: @carlpett: Add the error to the question, or else delete the question and ask a new proper one.

Comment: @Bo: True, the question can still be edited after closing in order to get reopened; however, I think most newcomers would see this as a sign of reject from the community, and would simply walk away. Anyway, this discussion is more suited to metaSO (and is already started: [grace period before closing question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/48433/158806), [min time allowed to edit before close](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48102/min-time-allowed-to-edit-a-question-before-closing-it), ...)

Comment: @Luc How about closing it in 19 seconds? :P  *@David* How do you know what he wants and what he tried? What he posted is not enough information

Comment: Sorry about the bad question. I assumed it was a well known restriction that is was not allowed to do such typedefs, and that there would be a common replacement. And for such a trivial error there would be no need for a longer explanation. However, the typedef was ok and worked when trying a minimal example. There is something else wrong in my code which gave me the impression that the typedef was to blame (yay for template compiler errors...). So I've deleted the post, but it seems it will remain a few days.

Comment: Well, according to @James Kanze, such typedefs are in fact not so ok. I take the liberty of posting his comment here since I deleted the (wrong) answer he commented on: "It's undefined behavior: §3.2.7/1 (point 2): "A name N used in a class S shall refer to the same declaration in its context and when re-evaluated in the completed scope of S. No diagnostic is required for a violation of this rule." G++ (at least with the options I use, including -std=c++98 -pendantic) refuses to compile it."

Comment: Interesting. I'm using MSVC 2010, and it compiles and runs fine. Even `/Wall` did not raise any warnings about it.

Comment: `typedef C1<T> C1;` is indeed ilegal

Comment: change the typedef name to something else like `typedef C1<T> C_`

Answer (score 0):

Use a macro. That's how I always do it since it's simple and easy to maintain.

Take this situation:

```
template <typename A, size_t B, int C, pointer_to_some_func D> class tTemplate
{
     struct myStruct
     {
         int i, j;
     };

     void function1 (tTemplate <A, B, C, D> :: myStruct S);
     void function2 ();
};

template <typename A, size_t B, int C, pointer_to_some_func D> void tTemplate <A, B, C, D> :: function1 (tTemplate <A, B, C, D> :: myStruct S)
{  
}
```

etc ...

Imagine if I had to change an argument or add another one...

Now, with this:

```
#define dTemplate tTemplate <A, B, C, D>
#define sTemplate template <typename A, size_t B, int C, pointer_to_some_func D>

sTemplate void dTemplate :: function1 (dTemplate::myStruct S)
{

}
```

Easier to maintain, useable by other classes\templates etc. One template argument change = a macro change which applies everywhere. And it is also nicer to the eyes.
Also, I find it a good thing in templates, especially since typedefs are no-go.
And best thing about macros, even IF typedefs were a standard: you don't need forward declarations for them... ever ! (yeah, macros are evil, but in situations like theese, they're more than useful)

As for your example:

```
#define dC1 C1 <T>       // no ";" !!!

template <typename T> class C1
{
    T t;
};

template <typename T> class C2
{
    dC1 c1;
};
```